# Error: could not decode result data (value="0x", info={ "method": "getCreatorCount", "signature": "getCreatorCount()" }, code=BAD_DATA, version=6.6.2)

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, decentralized-applications

I am using solidity and hardhat to create smart contract. Version 6.6.2. Here's how my smart contract looks like:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

contract CreatorRegistry {
    struct Creator {
        address walletAddress;
        string name;
        string b64Image;
    }

    Creator[] public creators;
    mapping(address => bool) public isCreatorRegistered;

    function signup(address _walletAddress, string memory _name, string memory _b64Image) public {
        require(!isCreatorRegistered[_walletAddress], "Address is already registered");

        Creator memory newCreator;
        newCreator.walletAddress = _walletAddress;
        newCreator.name = _name;
        newCreator.b64Image = _b64Image;

        creators.push(newCreator);
        isCreatorRegistered[_walletAddress] = true;
    }

    function getCreator(uint256 _index) public view returns (
        address walletAddress,
        string memory name,
        string memory b64Image
    ) {
        require(_index < creators.length, "Invalid index");

        Creator storage creator = creators[_index];
        walletAddress = creator.walletAddress;
        name = creator.name;
        b64Image = creator.b64Image;
    }

    function getCreatorCount() public view returns (uint256) {
        return creators.length;
    }
}
```

And here's how I am trying to invoke the contract:

```
// javascript frontend
const newUser =
                            (await registrationContract?.getCreatorCount?.()) ??
                            'Oops we lost';
                        console.log('New User = ', newUser);
```

But it fails with the error:

`Error: could not decode result data (value="0x", info={ "method": "getCreatorCount", "signature": "getCreatorCount()" }, code=BAD_DATA, version=6.6.2)`

Can someone help me in understanding what's going wrong here?

From the error it seems like its not able to decode the data in javascript side or is it an issue at solidity side? How can I fix this?

**Edit 1:**

As @Yilmaz mentioned in comments: `?.` is an optional chaining operator in javascript which ensures not to crash the program if the attribute remains undefined. However just to be super sure, I did this as well:

```
const newUserCount =
                            (await registrationContract.getCreatorCount()) ??
                            'Oops we lost';
```

which failed too.

**Edit 2**
Github forum: There's a github forum which suggests that due to varied network this issue may show up: https://github.com/web3/web3.js/issues/1629

So I was making sure that I am referring to localhost network and right wallet address. Even after configuring that, I am still getting the same error:
[image]

This is how my registrationContract looks like:

```
'use client';
import { Contract, InterfaceAbi, ethers } from 'ethers';
import Web3Modal from 'web3modal';
import { ContractRunner } from 'ethers';
import {
    contentCreatorABI,
    creatorRegistryABI,
    contentCreatorAddress,
    creatorRegistryAddress,
} from './contractClient';
import { Web3Window } from './web3SignIn';

const getSmartContract = (
    address: string,
    abi: InterfaceAbi,
    provider: ContractRunner
): Contract => new ethers.Contract(address, abi, provider);

const getContracts = async (): Promise<{
    error: boolean;
    message?: string;
    data?: { creatorContract?: Contract; registrationContract: Contract };
}> => {
    const { ethereum } = window as Web3Window;
    if (!ethereum)
        return {
            error: true,
            message: 'Please install metamask extension and try refreshing the page',
        };
    try {
        const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(ethereum);
        const signer = await provider.getSigner();
        const creatorContract = getSmartContract(
            contentCreatorAddress,
            contentCreatorABI,
            signer
        );
        const registrationContract = getSmartContract(
            creatorRegistryAddress,
            creatorRegistryABI,
            signer
        );

        return { error: false, data: { registrationContract } };
    } catch (err) {
        return { error: true, message: (err as { message: string }).message };
    }
};

export { getContracts };
```

Comment: you have a typo I think `await registrationContract?.getCreatorCount?.()` there is a dot "." before "()"

Comment: Ah that's chaining of javascript operator. I kept it in order to return if the function remains undefined. Even this isn't working: `const newUserCount =
       (await registrationContract.getCreatorCount()) ??
       'Oops we lost';`

Comment: How are you initialising `registrationContract` in your client app?

Comment: Hey! I have updated my question to include registration contract implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the error was coming because I was getting response from solidity in `uint8` which is equivalent to long in javascript and was required to correctly decrypted.

After decrypting it correctly, the issue went off.

Here's the final code:

at client side:

```
'use client';
import { Contract, InterfaceAbi, ethers } from 'ethers';
import { ContractRunner } from 'ethers';
import {
    contentCreatorABI,
    creatorRegistryABI,
    contentCreatorAddress,
    creatorRegistryAddress,
} from './contractClient';
import { Web3Window } from './web3SignIn';

const getSmartContract = (
    address: string,
    abi: InterfaceAbi,
    provider: ContractRunner
): Contract => new ethers.Contract(address, abi, provider);

const getContracts = async (): Promise<{
    error: boolean;
    message?: string;
    data?: { creatorContract: Contract; registrationContract: Contract };
}> => {
    const { ethereum } = window as Web3Window;
    if (!ethereum)
        return {
            error: true,
            message: 'Please install metamask extension and try refreshing the page',
        };
    try {
        const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(ethereum);
        const signer = await provider.getSigner();
        const creatorContract = getSmartContract(
            contentCreatorAddress,
            contentCreatorABI,
            signer
        );
        const registrationContract = getSmartContract(
            creatorRegistryAddress,
            creatorRegistryABI,
            signer
        );

        return { error: false, data: { registrationContract, creatorContract } };
    } catch (err) {
        return { error: true, message: (err as { message: string }).message };
    }
};

export { getContracts };
```

And here's how I invoke it:

```
'use client';
import { loginWithWallet } from '@@/solidity/web3SignIn';
import useWeb3Store from '@@/store/web3Walltet';
import classes from './MetaMaskLogin.module.css';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { getContracts } from '@@/solidity/contracts';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import { NormalImage } from '@@/components/NormalImage';

const MetaMaskLogin = () => {
    const {
        setAccount,
        setNameAndImg,
        setCreatorContract,
        setRegistrationContract,
        registrationContract,
        account,
    } = useWeb3Store();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);
    const [firstTime, setFirstTime] = useState(false);
    const [uName, setUName] = useState('');
    const [imgUrl, setImgUrl] = useState(
        'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/00000000000000000000000000000000'
    );

    const router = useRouter();

    const loginToMetaMask = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        loginWithWallet()
            .then((account) => {
                if (account) {
                    setAccount(account);
                } else
                    setError(
                        'Unexpected error occured while logging in. Please refresh the page and retry.'
                    );
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                setError(`Error occured while logging in: ${error.message}`);
            })
            .finally(() => setLoading(false));
    };

    const getUserDetails = async () => {
        if (registrationContract)
            try {
                const newUserCount =
                    (await registrationContract.getCreatorByAddress(account)) ??
                    'Oops we lost';
                const [_, name, b64Image] = newUserCount;
                if (name === 'Not Found') setFirstTime(true);
                else {
                    setFirstTime(false);
                    setNameAndImg(name, b64Image);
                    //TODO: Redirect to main page
                    router.push('/');
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.log('Error occured with smart contract = ', err);
            }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (account) {
            setLoading(true);
            getContracts()
                .then(async ({ error, data, message }) => {
                    if (!error && data) {
                        const { creatorContract, registrationContract } = data;
                        setCreatorContract(creatorContract);
                        setRegistrationContract(registrationContract);
                    } else
                        setError(
                            `Error occured while fetching smart contracts: ${
                                message ?? 'Unknown error'
                            }`
                        );
                })
                .catch((error) => setError(error.message))
                .finally(() => setLoading(false));
        }
    }, [account, setCreatorContract, setRegistrationContract]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getUserDetails();
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [registrationContract]);

    const registerUser = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        if (registrationContract) {
            const user = await registrationContract.signup(account, uName, imgUrl);
            await user.wait();
            setFirstTime(false);
            //TODO: Redirect to main page
            setLoading(false);
            router.push('/');
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className={classes.container}>
            <NormalImage
                className={classes.metamaskLogo}
                src='/meta-mask.png'
            />
            {loading ? (
                <p className={classes.SignInText}>Loading...</p>
            ) : (
                <button
                    className={'StandardButton'}
                    onClick={loginToMetaMask}
                >
                    Login to Metamask
                </button>
            )}
            {error != null && <p className={classes.ErrorText}>{error}</p>}
            {firstTime && (
                <>
                    <input
                        type='text'
                        className={classes.Input}
                        placeholder='Please Input your Name'
                        value={uName}
                        onChange={(e) => setUName(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <input
                        type='url'
                        className={classes.Input}
                        placeholder='Please Input your Image Avatar URL'
                        value={imgUrl}
                        onChange={(e) => setImgUrl(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <button
                        className='StandardButton'
                        onClick={registerUser}
                    >
                        Complete Registration
                    </button>
                </>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default MetaMaskLogin;
```

At server side:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

contract CreatorRegistry {
    struct Creator {
        address walletAddress;
        string name;
        string b64Image;
    }

    Creator[] public creators;
    mapping(address => bool) public isCreatorRegistered;

    function signup(address _walletAddress, string memory _name, string memory _b64Image) public {
        require(!isCreatorRegistered[_walletAddress], "Address is already registered");

        Creator memory newCreator;
        newCreator.walletAddress = _walletAddress;
        newCreator.name = _name;
        newCreator.b64Image = _b64Image;

        creators.push(newCreator);
        isCreatorRegistered[_walletAddress] = true;
    }

    function getCreator(uint256 _index) public view returns (
        address walletAddress,
        string memory name,
        string memory b64Image
    ) {
        require(_index < creators.length, "Invalid index");

        Creator storage creator = creators[_index];
        walletAddress = creator.walletAddress;
        name = creator.name;
        b64Image = creator.b64Image;
    }

    function getCreatorCount() public view returns (uint256) {
        return creators.length;
    }

    function getCreatorByAddress(address _walletAddress) public view returns (
        address walletAddress,
        string memory name,
        string memory b64Image
    ) {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < creators.length; i++) {
            Creator storage creator = creators[i];
            if (creator.walletAddress == _walletAddress) {
                walletAddress = creator.walletAddress;
                name = creator.name;
                b64Image = creator.b64Image;
                return (walletAddress, name, b64Image);
            }
        }

        // Creator not found
        return(walletAddress, "Not Found", "Not Found");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar situation and managed to solve it after I deployed the smart contract to my local network: npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.ts --network localhost

You can target any network from your Hardhat config using: npx hardhat run --network < your-network > scripts/deploy.js

Comment: Thank you but my issue was different. I got it sorted now!

Answer (score 1):

My problem was solved very simply, when calling a function that should return the owner's address

Solidity:

```
function callme() external view returns (address) {
    return msg.sender;
}
```

Ethers:

```
const callme = await Demo.callme();
console.log(callme);
```

I received an error:

> Error: could not decode result data (value="0x", info={ "method":
> "callme", "signature": "callme()" }, code=BAD_DATA, version=6.9.0)

By removing the `view` keyword from the function, everything worked, but the solidity compiler issues a warning in this case.

So, the answer for me is:

```
function callme() external returns (address) {
    return msg.sender;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that I had not run npm install and installed the dependencies in the project.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue

I had put my configuration inside `networks: { localhost: ... } }`, not realizing that Hardhat instead defaults the `hardhat` network.

To fix this, I set `defaultNetwork: 'localhost'`